# Symbol detection in scheme using Computer Vision

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, symbols

I am trying to detect electrical symbol in electrical scheme.
Here I think 2 ways could be use:

- classical way with OpenCV, I tried re to recognise shape with opencv and python but some symbole are too complexe
- deep learning way: I tried with Mask-RCNN using a handmade dataset of symbol but nothing get really successful

Here is a really simple example of what I would like to do:
[image]

I think it could be easy to make a dataset of symbol but all symbol would be the same form and context of the image would not be represented.

How do you think I could handle this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QATM:Quality-Aware Template Matching For Deep Learning might be what you are looking for.

Original paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07254

And the following github contain an example with electric scheme:
https://github.com/kamata1729/QATM_pytorch

[image]

Comment: I just tried their solution and that is working like a charm ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since the components of electrical scheme are always the same, I would try first Template Matching with OpenCV. I guess you will have to cut the components and make rotated copies to find all of them. It would be also nice to have better resolution of the images.

Next idea, I would say is making convolution with kernel which would be basicly the component you are expecting to be in the image.

Lastly, idea, which will give you definitely more certain results, but its pretty much overkill, is to use google image recognition, which you can use with python and train it on your images

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Comment: Oh thank you @Martin ! I didn't know this OpenCV function, I will try it and update my post following the result I got

Comment: @Kamloops yea, check it out. Also I updated my answer so give you extra ideas if the template matching doesnt work