# How to identify and count objects in pictures using python？

Tags: python, opencv

I want to recognize a specific shape in an image. First, I took a screenshot of the target in the image img-001.png and saved it as ant0.png. Then, using OpenCV-Python, I was able to recognize multiple ant0 in 001.png.

img-001.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktovV.png)

ant0.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0aDe.png)

img-002.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbBnp.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('img-001.png')

print(img_rgb.shape)
# Convert it to grayscale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('ant0.png',0)
# Store width and heigth of template in w and h
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# Perform match operations.
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
# Specify a threshold
# threshold = 0.84
threshold = 0.8
# Store the coordinates of matched area in a numpy array
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
x=loc[0]
y=loc[1]
# Draw a rectangle around the matched region.

ant_list=[]
if len(x) and len(y):
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)
        print((pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h))
        cv2.imwrite("ant-check0.png", img_rgb)
        ant_list.append(pt[0])
        print('I found the ant')

else:
    print('there is no ant')

print(len(ant_list))
cv2.imshow('ant-check1.png', img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I cannot recognize ant0 in similar images such as 002.png. How should I modify the code?

Comment: The lamp symbols in your first cicuit diagram are smaller than in the second. That is why `matchTemplate` won't find them. Is there a possibility that you make all input images have the same symbol resolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol detection in scheme using Computer Vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643717/symbol-detection-in-scheme-using-computer-vision)

Comment: How about object detection models like YOLO?